# Heroku Postgresql Database

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have created database in heroku hobby-dev and uploaded table from postgresql and used app.db.create_all() to trigger database model but its showing psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8 and suggesting us to install psycopg2-binary and we installed that too and still app.db.create_all() not working.

Answer (score 1):

The error doesn't relate to database Integration. There should be some error in Backend that's why It's giving 500.

For checking the error in heroku logs using heroku cli, use this :
`heroku logs -t`

Alternatively, you can view the logs on the App dashboard.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for Answering Sir. But when I disconnect database it running properly. Its taking me to success page but with database its showing this error.